# UI update from Class called by BackgroundWorker

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm using VS2017 and VB.NET.

I have a routine to work with files and show status-info at UI.  I'm used to work with different threads and updating UI controls using delegates.

My routine performs the following steps:

1. It starts a BackgroundWorker;
2. The BackgroundWorker loads a Class Module to perform the file operations;
3. In that CLASS module I call DELEGATES to update the NotifyIcon control and a custom performance-chart control, both in the main thread (UI).

The calls to NotifyIcon are functioning like a charm.

The calls to the performance-chart does not, but ONLY within the CLASS -
 any other call **functions normally within the BackgroundWorker DoWork event** and in any other part of the main form.

**The Delegate Call to the Performance control:**

```
Private Delegate Sub SetUIcallBack([controle] As Integer, [valor] As Integer)
```

**The Routine pointed by the above delegate:**

obs:
STATUSFILE is the control name and shows the performance BY FILE (percent);
STATUSALL is the control name and shows the count of files in a list of files:

```
Friend Sub ThreadSafe_CircularProgress(WhichControl As Integer, Value As Integer)

Try

If WhichControl = Circular.ByFile Then

        If Me.StatusFile.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetUIcallBack(AddressOf ThreadSafe_CircularProgress)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {WhichControl, Value})
        Else
            StatusFile.Value = Value
            StatusFile.Refresh()
        End If

    ElseIf WhichControl = Circular.AllFiles Then

        If Me.StatusAll.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetUIcallBack(AddressOf ThreadSafe_CircularProgress)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {WhichControl, Value})
        Else
            StatusAll.Valor = Value
            StatusAll.Refresh()
        End If

    End If

Catch ex As Exception

End Try

End Sub
```

**The BackgroundWorker DoWork event:**

```
  Dim CurrentFile as integer = 1


  Using MyClass as new CLASSE_ARQUIVO()

  For Each Arquivo As String In Argumentos.Arquivos
          ThreadSafe_CircularProgress(Circular.ByFile, 0)  <- It is working OK
          dim Result as boolean = MyClass.PerformFileOps(Arquivo)

          if Result = True              
             ThreadSafe_CircularProgress(Circular.ByFile, 100)  <- It is working OK
             CurrentFile += 1
             ThreadSafe_CircularProgress(Circular.AllFiles, CurrentFile)   <- It is working OK
          end if

   next

  End Using
```

So, everything above is functioning as required. No problem at all.

But, when the application goes into the CLASSE_ARQUIVO, I suppose to change/update the **Circular.ByFile** control with the percentual value of the running process, using the following instruction:

```
Form1.ThreadSafe_CircularProgress(Circular.ByFile, X)
```

where "X" is the current percentual value.

Some things I can see there:

1. The Sub "ThreadSafe_CircularProgress" is really called normally...
2. For my surprise, the INVOKEREQUIRED is false (`If Me.StatusFile.InvokeRequired`)
3. The execution pointer goes into the `StatusFile.Value = Value` and nothing happens in UI, not even if (in debug-mode) I deviate the pointer into the INVOKEREQUIRED (to force the DELEGATE call).

Curiously, inside the same CLASS, I call a similar sub to update NotifyIcon balloon with status information (like "the file is 20% processed") and, in this case, the control responds normally.

Important to say the "Circular" routine is functioning normally in the entire program - the problem is related ONLY during the calls made within the CLASS.

**UPDATE**

Even if, in Class, I call the BackgroundWorker.Progress event, I see the code pointer going there, calling (and running accordingly) the DELEGATE function, but the control does not change its value (zero). Eg.:

```
 Form1.Backgroundworker.ReportProgress(20)  <- It does not function...
```

Obviously, the Report flag of BackgroundWorker is active... the problem is related *only* to the call inside the Class.

Comment: You've got an empty try/catch there... is an exception being swallowed?

Comment: @nicko, I put a TRY-CATCH in code and no exception is being fired at all. Thanks!